# cannot read property 'getCurrentPosition' into react native project

Tags: react-native, geolocation

**Context :**

- Project : React-native
- Init : expo init project
- test env : Android device + web browser
- React native version : 0.71.8
- React version : 18.2.0

I want to try to work with Geolocation into device for react-native project

**Issue :**

cannot read property 'getCurrentPosition' with 2 differents react-native library

*with :*

```
import Geolocation from 'react-native-geolocation-service'
Geolocation.getCurrentPosition()
```

*or with :*

```
import Geolocation from '@react-native-community/geolocation'
Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(info => console.log(info))
```

Impossible to get Position into Android device (but ok into browser web)

What is the best official library for working with geolocation into react native ?

Needs 2 base code ? One for iOS other for Android ?

Just 1 library can work into iOS and Android ?

Why I can't 'getCurrentPosition' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using Expo, use the Geolocation package optimized for Expo ecosystem - https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/location/

Comment: OK I'm new to react-native eco-system. Expo tool seems to be a very large complete solution with lot of libraries that can be use instead of other in the web. Thank you.